# Stop compiler from generating wrappers for imported functions

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly, visual-c++, kernel

I'm trying to get address of KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex but compiler keeps generating function that calls KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex and I get address of this generated function. I could parse PE exports but I wanted to know if there is a way to stop this behaviour I'm using Visual Studio. I tried to disable all optimizations but that doesn't change anything.

```
uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex; // gets address of KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex_0 

KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex_0 proc near
jmp     cs:__imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex
KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex_0 endp
```

Comment: you need disable [`/INCREMENTAL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/incremental-link-incrementally?view=vs-2019) linker option - what you see - this is *jump thunk* or alternative you can do this from asm code - declare `extern __imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex:QWORD` and read value from `__imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex`. you can do this in case x64 and direct from c++ - declare extern "C" { extern void* __imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex; } and use it addr as is. but here will be problem with x86 name - `__imp__KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex@8`

Comment: which is not valid c++ name (@ symbol)

Comment: oo. now look in *wdm.h* - this function declared without `__declspec(dllimport)` attribute. and exactly this produce jmp thunk on function.

Answer (score 3):

That's just how imported functions work in Windows.  The compiler isn't generating the code you're seeing, it's actually in the import library you linked with, which was previously generated by the linker that created the import library.  (Actually, with modern import libraries and linkers, the import records are stored in a compact form and the linker generates the code at link time. Either way it's not generated by the compiler itself.)

If `addr` is a local variable or you're using C++ then `uintptr_t addr =(uintptr_t)KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex;` can be resolved at runtime during initialization, and it will contain the actual address of the function.  For this to work though `KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex` has to be previously declared `__declspec(dllimport)` otherwise the compiler won't know that it's an imported function whose real address isn't located in the same image.  Apparently the DDK headers are missing this, so that's why you're not getting the actual address of the function in `addr`.

If `addr` isn't a local variable and you're using C, or `__declspec(dllimport)` wasn't used, as appears to be the case here, the definition is resolved at link time, and the linker doesn't know and can't know what address of the function will be at runtime.  Instead it uses the address of the stub function, the one that import library implicitly or explicitly defines, since it does know where the stub will be relative to the start of the image it creates.

The simple solution is to just obtain the real address of the function at runtime in your own code.  Since this is kernel code you'll need to use [`MmGetSystemRoutineAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-mmgetsystemroutineaddress), as Maxim Sagaydachny said:

```
uintptr_t addr = MMGetSystemRoutineAddress("KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex");
```

If you want to go the hard route, so you can avoid calling `MMGetSystemRoutineAddress`, you can do something like this:

```
#ifdef _M_IX86

extern "C" NTSTATUS  (__stdcall *_imp__KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndexw)(ULONG, PROCESSOR_NUMBER);
#pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:__imp__KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex=__imp__KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex@8")
uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)_imp__KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex;

#elif defined(_M_X64) 

extern "C" NTSTATUS (__stdcall *__imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex)(ULONG, PROCESSOR_NUMBER);
uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)__imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex;

#endif
```

But I'm not sure it's worth all this code complexity, and relying on a undocumented linker switch in the 32-bit x86 case, just to save a function call. The code is also specific to Visual C++, though it could be adapted for Clang or GCC.

You can find more detail about how `__declspec(dllimport)` works in [this answer by Matteo Italia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671021/use-case-of-dllimport-in-visualstudio/24671507#24671507), and much more detail in the blogs by Raymond Chen linked to in that answer.

Comment: *how imported functions work in Windows* - not exactly. for import function compiler declare `__imp_fn` variable (for *x86* or c++ name `fn` will be decorated). when need call api - will be `call __imp_fn` instruction, when need take function address -say  `mov rax,__imp_fn` instruction - so this take real address for `__imp_fn` variable. but with [`/INCREMENTAL`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/incremental-link-incrementally?view=vs-2019) option - code *May contain jump thunks* - `fn: jmp __imp_fn` - so this is jump think and with this instead of real address we got

Comment: address of thunk - `lea rax, fn` where `fn` is label for `fn:jmp __imp_fn` instead `mov rax,__imp_fn`

Comment: @RbMm  As usual, I can't really make sense of what you're trying to say, but you don't seem to be actually contradicting anything I wrote.  Instead you've brought up the optimizations the compiler can perform in certain cases when a function has been declared with `__declspec(dllimport)` but this isn't one of those cases.  It's not possible for the compiler to use the `__imp__fn` symbol directly when statically initializing a statically defined variable like with `uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex;`.

Comment: sorry for my pure english . but you serios mistake. this is **possible** to compiler direct use  `__imp__fn`. we we also can do this is code - (i do this not once) - we can simply declare `extern "C" { extern void* __imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex; }` and use `__imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex` as is (but for x86 need trick here). what you see `jmp __imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex` - this is jump thunk due /INCREMENTAL option. and this is change address

Comment: value of `void* __imp_fn` (real function address) and adress of thunk (inside our module) - different addresses

Comment: Your *`uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t)KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex;` definition is resolved at link* - this is **not true**. this is resolved to `mov rax, __imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex; mov addr, rax` or too `lea rax, fn; mov addr, rax` (when fn - this is **jmp thunk** inside our module) at link time resolved only value inside `void* __imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex` variable

Comment: @RbMm True, in C++, it's resolved by dynamic initialization code.  In C, as I was assuming, it's resolved at link time statically as I said.  However, what I said in the first paragraph is correct. The import stub functions are defined by the import library, either explicitly or implicitly, and in the C case or any other case where the compiler can't substitute the `__imp__fn` symbol the import stub functions are used instead.

Comment: no. are *c* or *c++* here not importand. i look now in *wdm.h* `KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex` declaration - problem in this point - it declared without `__declspec(dllimport)`. really when we declare function with this attribute - **variable** implicitly declared by compiler `void* __imp_fn` and used. at link time resolved **value** stored in this variable, but not code for **use** this variable. and we can explicitly declare this variable by self and use it.

Comment: but without __declspec(dllimport) or with /INCREMENTAL option - jmp thunk is created. address stored in **variable** __imp_fn and address of jump thunk - 2 absolute different addresses

Comment: jump thunk in .lib is created either way no? But a linker that understands dllimport will ignore the jump thunk and use the address in the import section directly.

Comment: @Anders Linkers don't understand `dllimport`, the compiler has no way of telling the linker that a symbol was declared with it or not. The compiler either generates code that uses `__imp__fn` or just `_fn`.  Since this code is very different because the former is a pointer to a function and the later is an actual function, the linker can't change the later into the former. If the compiler uses `_fn` it's too late for the linker to change it into `__imp_fn`. (Obviously this ignores link time code generation where the linker actually compiles the code.)

Comment: if i correct understand OP question - it need take **real** address of `KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex` this address was inside `__imp_KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex` variable (for x64, for x86 inside `__imp__KeGetProcessorNumberFromIndex@8`) we can direct declare and use this variable with `extern` (but here problem for x86) or read it value by asm code (possible inline asm in x86).

Answer (score -1):

use MmGetSystemRoutineAddress to get address of required function.
it is kernel equivalent of userspace LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress